# How does Magneto control the Sentinels?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, magneto, marvel

In X-Men: Days of Future Past, Magneto is shown commanding one of the Sentinels to

> **"Do what you were made for!"**

Why would the Sentinels accept any voice command from Magneto?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the scene where Magneto infiltrates metal into the bodies of each of the sentinels, there's a "blink and you'll miss it" animation where the metal invades the CPU of the robot, activating it and (presumably) allowing Magneto to take control of it.

Quite how he reprograms them isn't described in detail but as the old adage goes, there's no access like physical access.

[image]

Comment: I guess that would also explain why the Sentinels don't attack Magneto himself, since they're programmed to eliminate mutants and target the X-gene.

Comment: This is why you need to security-check your giant robots against mutant hacking attempts.

Comment: @zibbobz - Well that's just basic common sense. You'd think they'd cover that on day one of any recognised IT qualification.

Comment: He obviously used that ages-old [bash bug](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/09/24/bash_shell_vuln/).

Comment: Huh.  Looks like you're right, but I always thought that he simply controlled the metal which was now throughout the robot's entire body.  So even if they wanted to attack him, they weren't physically able to.  As an engineer, I find this explanation a dubious proposition.  He must have had the CPU's spec on hand...

Comment: How did he reprogram them? It's clearly an injection attack.

Comment: Obviously he used his powers to flip the parity switch labeled "Humans/Mutants".

Comment: Or possibly he could *read* the CPU well enough to determine its specs

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought but maybe he put them in "opposite mode". Instead of killing mutants &  protecting humans, they somehow where switched to killing humans and protecting mutants. Just a guess from observing the behavior of sententials in the past

Comment: Nope. Magneto was having them target mutants, too, which in why Beast had to take those gene suppressing injections to avoid being targeted.

Comment: you mean like in x-men 2?