# Does Magneto have more powers in the movie X-Men: Days of Future Past?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, magneto, marvel

In the movie X-Men : Days of Future Past, Magneto is shown not only controlling metal but breaking it down to microscopic level, inserting it into 8 different robots at the same time, controlling and operating these robots and their internal parts and system that he hasn't seen. Doesn't that give him the power of omniscience or at least more than his *original* powers? I don't think he ever has these powers in the comic books or in any of his appearance in movies or book.

**EDIT**
 The movie shows him having an extra power than his real and original powers. He can only control the metal, not control the operating system of other robots with the help of metal he just broke down. Apart from that, who's to say that the main functioning core and system of those robots was made up of pure metal? It could have been anything. But he altered their programming and turned them against the good guys without having any knowledge of science or programming.

Comment: i believe its simply that he can feel the metal inside of the robots, and so essentially can "see" whats inside because its metal.

Comment: Omniscience - [having complete or unlimited knowledge, awareness, or understanding; perceiving all things.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk)

Comment: So that gives him an extra power than his real and original powers. He can only control the metal, not control the operating system of other robots with the help of metal he just broke down. Apart from that, who's to say that the main functioning core and system of those robots was made up of pure metal. It could have been anything. But he altered their programming and turned them against the good guys without having any knowledge of science or programming.

Comment: @Richard Thanks. Guys, I found the answer to this Question: [Answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68538/how-does-magneto-control-the-sentinels)

Comment: I've closed this since OP is happy to accept that this is a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Magneto gained access to microfilm schematics of the Sentinel design. We can assume that it included how different parts of the Sentinel interact. Magneto can then use either direct metal injection (fuzzing, shorting) or electromagnetic control (which has always been part of his powers. Since at least the 90s.) To control an advanced-for-the-60s computer.

Then again, the Sentinels have technology more advanced than us, including real time digital motion and people tracking,  hover jets, AI, etc.

Comment: do you mean 'fusing'?

Comment: @thepop nope.  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing

Comment: how do you do this with metal particles?

Comment: @thepop Google **hardware fuzzing** and **circuit bending**.